# Facebook sdk FB.login error : Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm totally struggling with facebook sdk.

I just want to be able to create a "publish my score" button in a facebook canvas app.

So I've made a button:

```
<a href="#" onclick="GlobalCallback.postScore([score here])"></a>
```

and the content of postScore is:

```
postScore: function(score) {
        FB.login(function(response) {

        }, {scope: "public_profile,email,publish_stream"});
    }
```

But all I get is a:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null

I actually tried other things like calling FB.ui but I also get the same error...

EDIT:

The error happens directly on FB.login, or even FB.ui..

EDIT2:

Ok so after other tests I realize that's related to the way these methods are called, they have to be originated from an onclick event, which I already knew from the doc.. BUT not any  onclick events, looks like the way jquery or reatjs do it won't work, it has to be done from a button written in the html.

I tried reactJS events, jquery .click() method, jquery's on("click"), and setting "onclick" through jquery's attr() method. None of them work.

but

```
<button onclick="login()" />
```

works..

Comment: publish_stream is deprecated since years, not sure why people still use it. use publish_actions.

Comment: that being said, make sure the js sdk is initialized correctly, and debug your code. see where the error happens exactly.

Comment: Hi luschn thanks for reply, I edited my question. That's actually the main problem here, there's not much to debug. I just call FB.login ou FB.ui and after that point I'm into minified code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally got it the error "Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null" comes from XDM which I don't know much about, looks like it creates an iframe for communication.

The thing is that I rendered my pages directly in the document.body thus destroying the iframe and all.