# Facebook Page Tab FB.login Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, turbolinks-5

Hello I’m creating a facebook page tab in which the owner of the facebook page will be able to sell anything.

So, when someone visits the page and click the checkout button the app calls the FB.login method and I get the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null
  at ha (sdk.js:95)
  at Object.ba [as send] (sdk.js:95)
  at i.<anonymous> (sdk.js:105)
  at i.window.FB.i.enqueue (sdk.js:89)
  at sa (sdk.js:105)
  at i.<anonymous> (sdk.js:105)
  at i.window.FB.i.enqueue (sdk.js:89)
  at i.$JSONRPC4 (sdk.js:99)
  at i.<anonymous> (sdk.js:98)
  at la (sdk.js:142)
```

My code is here.

```
$('.login-checkout').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    checkLoginState('checkout');
});

function facebookLogin(action) {
  FB.login(function(response) {
        window.location = '/facebook?action=' + action + '&access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken;
  }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
}

function checkLoginState(action) {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if(response.status === 'connected') {
        window.location = '/facebook?action=' + action + '&access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken;
    } else {
        facebookLogin(action);
    }
  });
}
```

The response.status of FB.getLoginStatus is `not_authorized`. 
I use the javascript SDK

Comment: did you authorize already? you are trying to use FB.login in the asynchronous callback of getLoginStatus, don´t do that. browsers will most likely block the popup.

Comment: anyway, there are many threads about that error already, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669255/facebook-sdk-fb-login-error-cannot-read-property-postmessage-of-null

Comment: or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476781/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-postmessage-of-undefined-error-whi

Comment: also, read this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: I changed the way I call the `FB.login` and I get the same error. I already read the threads you mention but they didn't help me